# jenkins job builder not working: jenkins-jobs update jobs/

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

### jenkins-jobs update jobs/

## **error**

INFO:jenkins_jobs.cli.subcommand.base:Updating jobs in [PosixPath('/home/ishu/jobs')] ([])
INFO:root:Caching type builders of builders = jenkins_jobs.modules.builders:Builders
INFO:jenkins_jobs.builder:Number of jobs generated:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 822, in get_info
return json.loads(self.jenkins_open(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 560, in jenkins_open
return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 576, in jenkins_request
self.maybe_add_crumb(req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 373, in maybe_add_crumb
response = self.jenkins_open(requests.Request(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 560, in jenkins_open
return self.jenkins_request(req, add_crumb, resolve_auth).text
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 579, in jenkins_request
self._request(req))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 553, in _request
return self._session.send(r, **_settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 483, in send
timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 119, in **init**
self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 156, in _validate_timeout
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x7fece1460800>, but it must be an int, float or None.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ishu/.local/bin/jenkins-jobs", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cli/entry.py", line 179, in main
jjb.execute()
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cli/entry.py", line 158, in execute
ext.obj.execute(self.options, self.jjb_config)
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cli/subcommand/update.py", line 133, in execute
jobs, num_updated_jobs = builder.update_jobs(
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 332, in update_jobs
results = self.parallel_update_job(n_workers=n_workers, concurrent=p_params)
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/parallel.py", line 113, in concurrentized
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 353, in parallel_update_job
self.update_job(job.name, job.output().decode("utf-8"))
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 132, in update_job
if self.is_job(job_name):
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 143, in is_job
if job_name in self.job_list:
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 102, in job_list
self._job_list = set(job["fullname"] for job in self.jobs)
File "/home/ishu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 94, in jobs
self._jobs = self.jenkins.get_all_jobs()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 1074, in get_all_jobs
jobs = [(0, [], self.get_info(query=jobs_query)['jobs'])]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line 829, in get_info
raise JenkinsException("Could not parse JSON info for server[%s]"
jenkins.JenkinsException: Could not parse JSON info for server[http://localhost:9090/]

```
raise JenkinsException("Could not parse JSON info for server[%s]"
```

jenkins.JenkinsException: Could not parse JSON info for server[http://localhost:9090/]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in the *urllib3* library: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-jenkins/+bug/2018567
There  are several solution to fixing this but the most straight-forward one is to add in your config file (e.g. *jenkins_jobs.ini*) the *timeout* property, down in the **[jenkins]** section, like so:

```
[...]

[jenkins]
user=youruser
password=yourpassword
url=http://localhost:9090/
timeout=60
query_plugins_info=False
##### This is deprecated, use job_builder section instead
#ignore_cache=True

[...]
```

At the moment, this is still reproducible in Python 3.11.4 (which is what I'm using), so hopefully this will get fixed once the patch https://review.opendev.org/c/jjb/python-jenkins/+/882757 is being merged.